# How can I convert a PDF file to HTML, Word, Excel and Image file?

Tags: c#, pdf

I am using C# 2.0 and developing an application to convert a PDF file into HTML, Word, Excel and Image (GIF,JPEG,PNG,TIFF). Is there any free library / class available for that?

Comment: Aren't *you* the one supposed to be developing an app that does that? If you use a library, what will there be left for you to do?

Comment: I am not an expert coder to write my own library

Answer (score 1):

[Solid Framework](http://www.soliddocuments.com/) does a good job with PDF files. Not free though. I have tried iTextSharp and PDFBox and I can say PDFBox is rather easy if you just need the text content.

Answer (score 1):

The [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) library allows you to manipulate PDF files. You should be able to build what you need from it.

I know you want a free library, but a good library I've used is [Windward .NET reporting engine](http://www.windwardreports.com/dot_net.htm). It is very expensive, though.